# Xamarin - Binding to a Property of a child control inside a custom control

Tags: xamarin, bindableproperty

I am working on a Xamarin App.  I am making a custom control with a Label control, a DatePicker control and an Entry control.  I had to create quite a few BindableProperties for the Date Control in the Custom Control such as MaximumDate, MinimumDate Property among many other properties.  As far as I understand, the reason I have to create these BindableProperty members in my Custom control are because I have no access to the properties of the child controls when the custom control is used on a view.  Is there a way to access the properties of the child control that is embedded in a custom control? I could save a lot of lines of code defining the BindableProperties and their CLR properties and other things.

Here is my Custom control XAML (I have removed all the elements except for a Label element in the posted code to make the code more readable and for brevity.

```
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DPSReminders.Controls.CustomLabel"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DPSReminders.Controls"
         xmlns:sfLayout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TextInputLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
         xmlns:sfPicker="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Pickers;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPicker.XForms"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         xmlns:fai="clr-namespace:FontAwesome">
<StackLayout.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</StackLayout.Resources>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
    <Label x:Name="myLabel" 
            Text=""
            FontFamily="FASolid"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Margin="10">
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

The code behind file:

```
public class CustomLabel : StackLayout
{
public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelText), typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel),
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: LabelTextPropertyChanged);

public string LabelText
{
    get => GetValue(LabelTextProperty)?.ToString();
    set => SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
}

private static void LabelTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = bindable as CustomLabel;
    control.myLabel.Text = newValue?.ToString();
}

public CustomLabel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
}
```

Here is the page where I am trying to use the custom control.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DPSReminders.Views.DateTimeTest"
         xmlns:fai="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DPSReminders.ViewModels"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DPSReminders.Controls"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         >
    <controls:CustomLabel LabelText = "{Binding MyLabelText}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

I am wondering if I could do a line like this in my label, that would make my life much easier.

```
    <controls:CustomLabel:myLabel.Text = "{Binding MyLabelText}"/>
```

Then, I can remove all the code creating the BindableProperties and the supporting CLR properties etc. when a built-in bindable property for the same purpose is already available in the child control.  Is this something we can do?

Comment: I couln't see any reason for not  to work. Does it work when you set manually instead of binding like `<controls:CustomLabel LabelText = "Hello World"/>` ?

Comment: It does work when I bind to the bindableproperty I created such as "LabelText".  My question was if there is a way to bind to the underlying Label's Text property directly like this: <controls:CustomerLabel:myLabel.Text = "{Binding MyLabelText}"/>  instead of this: <controls::CustomLabel LabelText = "{Binding MyLabelText}"/>.  This will eliminate quite a lot of lines of code creating BindableProperties and the regular properties to support it and any PropertyChanged handling etc.

Comment: how about use template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template

Comment: Thanks Adrian; sorry for the delay responding.  I took a look at your suggestion.  Though I was looking for not duplicating already existing bindableproperites altogether, I think this is still a better approach than what I was able to come up with.  So, If you post this comment as a reply, I will mark it as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using template instead.

Xamarin.Forms control templates enable you to define the visual structure of ContentView derived custom controls, and ContentPage derived pages. Control templates separate the user interface (UI) for a custom control, or page, from the logic that implements the control or page. Additional content can also be inserted into the templated custom control, or templated page, at a pre-defined location.

**Doc link:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template